# Merge two linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, linear-transformations

For $m\times n$ matrices $A,B$ and $n$-dimensional column vectors $a,b$, assume we are looking for $x$ so that $Ax=a$ and $Bx=b$. Then $x$ should be in the intersection of the two solution sets.

(**We may assume $m<n$ and $A,B$ themselves as well as all $m\times m$ submatrices of $A$, $B$ have rank $m$.**)

I am wondering is there a way to merge these two linear systems to one, so that the solution set of some $Cy=c$ **has the same size as** (or a little bit larger than but is not too far away from) the solution set of all $x$ as above?

(It means we may recover $x$ from $y$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use

$$C := \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix},$$

$$y = \begin{pmatrix} x  \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$c = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can simply stack it:
$$
\binom{A}{B}x
= \binom{a}{b}
$$